# How can I edit focused text field? (Swift, macOS)

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to make little utility for macOS(not iOS) using by Swift(newbie).

I guess this utility would be 
command line tool triggered by other apps or
Menu bar application.

I implemented features that I've wanted,
but I have no idea how to edit focused text field.

e.g. Get text from a text editor(atom, sublime, ... when this app triggered.) and make some changes on that text and paste back to the text editor.

I want to make this app works on system-wide,

I want to know how to implement things below

> 1. Get text from currently active/focused text field.
> 2. Delete text on currently active/focused text field.
> 3. Paste text to currently active/focused text field.
>      (text means just one word or line before the cursor)

I'm trying this on command line tool and keyboard event(CGEvent) now which seems no good idea.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you need to implement a `system service`, like described in the [docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/introduction.html).

   The relevant parts (although you need to read it all) are [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/Articles/using.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000854-97617) in the section "Sending Data to the Service" or "Receiving Data from the Service" (it's done using the pasteboard).
2. As an alternate solution (maybe better) you should consider packaging your app as a share app extension (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-extensions/))

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the macOS accessibility features in the [ApplicationServices framework](https://developer.apple.com/reference/applicationservices). Specifically, the classes with an "AX" prefix (these are the accessibility ones). It's not the prettiest thing to work with (especially in Swift) but you can achieve what you want with it.